# How do I connect AWS API Gateway to an internal NLB/ALB using SSL without a public certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a public API Gateway REST API that I need to connect to an internal NLB/ALB.  All communications must be SSL for compliance reasons.

The current configuration is that API Gateway uses SSL for incoming connections, then proxies via VPC Link to a non-SSL private AWS Network Load Balancer, which in turn connects to an Application Load Balancer.

- Note:  API Gateway REST APIs cannot use VPCLink to connect to an ALB directly, so it must connect to a NLB pointing to the ALB.  HTTP APIs permit a direct connection.

GET https:///sample/api
API Gateway proxy integration (VPC Link) to NLB in a private VPC subnet
NLB Routes to a single ALB
ALB routes to the appropriate back-end server based on the characteristics of the request.

According to the [API Gateway documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html), it will only permit the use of SSL certificates using a [supported CA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-supported-certificate-authorities-for-http-endpoints.html)

What are my possible solutions here?   I want to avoid having to get a public certificate for a private resource.
Thus far I've tried:
I've set up the ALB with a private certificate using with an internal CA.
API Gateway will not connect through to the back-end because it does not recognize the internal CA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

hi let me se if I got your question. you want to avoid the use of a public certificate on your NLB? I understand the use of SSL in all the communication process but I can tell you that forwarding from NLB to ALB is unnecessary. instead you can use the same certificate on your NLB that is actually using the ALB and remove the ALB from the stack. about the use of certificates ¿you are using AWS CAM right?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there are only 2 options for ALB to receive traffic from API Gateway private integration:

1. is the public certificate that you excluded
2. Disable ALB certificate verification setting `insecureSkipVerification = false`, that is not recommended. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_TlsConfig.html

The supported CAs cannot be changed, so a private CA is not currently supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-supported-certificate-authorities-for-http-endpoints.html

Answer (score -2):

Given your requirements and the limitations of API Gateway, there are a couple of potential solutions to connect your public API Gateway REST API to an internal NLB/ALB using SSL without having to obtain a public certificate for the private resource.

**Use ACM Private CA**:
Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) Private Certificate Authority allows you to create and manage a private CA that can issue private certificates for internal resources. With this approach, you can use ACM Private CA to generate SSL certificates for your internal NLB and ALB. API Gateway should recognize certificates issued by ACM Private CA, even if they are not from a public CA.
Follow these steps:

1. Set up an ACM Private CA and generate SSL certificates for your
   internal NLB and ALB using that private CA.
2. Configure the NLB and ALB to use the certificates issued by ACM
   Private CA. Use the NLB endpoint as the target for your API
   Gateway's VPC Link.
3. Ensure that the NLB forwards traffic to the ALB, and the ALB routes
   the requests to the backend servers.

This way, you can maintain SSL encryption between API Gateway and the internal NLB/ALB without relying on public certificates.

For a detailed explanation and examples - refer to these ([ACM private CA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKymN_ICpv8), [ACM + ELB AWS doc](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb) and [Configure Elastic Load Balancing With SSL And AWS Certificate Manager For Bitnami Applications On AWS](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/))

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've created a Private Certificate Authority and generated a certificate.   According to the [Private Certificate Authority user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/privateca/latest/userguide/PcaWelcome.html), certificates issued by a private CA are trusted only within your organization.  The private CA doesn't appear to be recognized by API Gateway, likely because it is not in the [API Gateway supported CAs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-supported-certificate-authorities-for-http-endpoints.html).   Do you have a working example?

Comment: When I configure port 443 on the NLB to point to https on the ALB using a private CA and attempt to connect via API Gateway, I receive the following message.  
`Execution failed due to configuration error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: The supported CAs cannot be changed. A private CA is not currently supported https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-supported-certificate-authorities-for-http-endpoints.html